# How to convert int to decimal in BizTalk orchestration xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath, biztalk

How to convert int to decimal in Orchestration using xpath ? My QuantityReturned field is type integer in my schema when it calls the webservice it converts to decimal and call the webservice. Below is the xpath query for  QuantityReturned.

```
QuantityReturned=xpath(OrderReturnMessage, 
                       "number(/*[local-name()='QuantityReturned' and namespace-uri()=''])");

wSReturnSuccess = WebServiceHelper.CreateReturnAAAWS
                       (System.Convert.ToDecimal(QuantityReturned));
```

When tried with number function in xpath query, throw error that input string is not correct format.

Comment: What is the representation of `QuantityReturned` and what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that your xpath is incorrect and returning a value which cannot be converted to decimal.

Can you evaluate your xpath against the message xml and see what is actually returned? Your current expression resolves to the value of an unqualified, root-level element called QuantityReturned.

Unless your message xml matches this, your xpath will likely return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tom Redfern's answer, which is likely the root cause, I would recommend refactoring this into a call in an external assembly, such as:

```
public static decimal StringToDecimal(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        // log error, throw exception, or just return a default value if acceptable
    }
    decimal d;
    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out d))
    {
        return d;
    }
    else 
    {
        // appropriately log errors and/or throw a more meaningful exception
    }
}
```

You could also look into some of the `NumberStyles` options that the other overload of [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) offers.

You **could** do this in an orchestration, but if this method becomes any more complex it's going to start looking really ugly in the expression editor - even as it is it will look a little ugly in the expression editor.